# Unable to connect react drag and drop with backend in MERN

Tags: javascript, mern, react-beautiful-dnd

I have implemented a simple drag and drop code here below using react-beautiful-dnd. The frontend alone works perfectly fine, however, when I tried to connect this with the backend the items in the droppable context are unable to be dragged. That is, I am unable to drag the items within the column and also between columns. Further, I am unable to figure out how to pass the index of the elements in the mongoDb database.

The code I used is here below

projectsDashboard.js

```
function ProjectsDashboard() {


 const handleDragEnd = ({destination, source}) => {
   if (!destination) {
     return
   }

   if (destination.index === source.index && destination.droppableId === source.droppableId) {
     return
   }

   // Creating a copy of item before removing it from state
   const itemCopy = {...state[source.droppableId].items[source.index]}

   setState(prev => {
     prev = {...prev}
     // Remove from previous items array
     prev[source.droppableId].items.splice(source.index, 1)


     // Adding to new items array location
     prev[destination.droppableId].items.splice(destination.index, 0, itemCopy)

     return prev
   })
 }

const dispatch = useDispatch();
useEffect(() => {
  dispatch(getStages());
},[dispatch]);
const { stage } = useSelector(state => state.stage);

var formattedArray = stage.map(item => Object.keys(item).map(i => item[i]));
  console.log(formattedArray)

 return ( 
<DragDropContext  onDragEnd={handleDragEnd}>
  
       {_.map(state, (data, key) => {
         return(
           <div key={key} className={"column"}>
             {console.log(key , "KEY")}
             <ProjectWrapper className="border">
               
              
             <h3 className="title">{data.title}</h3>
             </ProjectWrapper>
             <Droppable droppableId={key}>
              
               {(provided, snapshot) => {
                 return(
                   <div>
              
                   <div
                     ref={provided.innerRef}
                     {...provided.droppableProps}
                     className={"droppable-col"}
                   >
                         <hr className="line" style={{opacity: 10 }}></hr>       
                   

                              
                     {stage.map(stages=>{
                       if(stages.status == key)
                       return(
                         <Draggable key={stages._id} 
                     
                         //index={index} 
                         draggableId={stages._id} className="drag">
                           {(provided, snapshot) => {
                             console.log(snapshot)
                             return(
                               <div
                                 className={`item ${snapshot.isDragging && "dragging"}`}
                                 ref={provided.innerRef}
                                 {...provided.draggableProps}
                                 {...provided.dragHandleProps}
                               >
                                 {/* card name */}
                            
                                   <button className="stageDetails" style={{padding: "0",border: "none", background: "none"}}>
                                       {stages.stageName}
                                  </button>
                                  <DeleteOutlinedIcon className="delete" />
                               </div>
                             )
                           }}
                         
                         </Draggable>
                       )
                     })}
                     {provided.placeholder}
                   </div>
                   </div>
                 )
               }}
             </Droppable>

           </div>
         )
       })}
     </DragDropContext>
   </div>

 );



};

export default ProjectsDashboard;
```

Comment: Just from looking at your code, it doesn’t seem you connected your backend to your frontend- are you fetching data or uploading somewhere else?

Comment: @LiorPollak I am fetching data using redux and controllers